# Phone Not Seeing School Wifi

Tags: wi-fi

When I go to school and try to connect to the wifi network (with my Blu Life One X) it doesn't show any of the networks. The thing is that when I am at home I can see and use the wifi network and at school many times I'll see other peoples wifi hot spots available. So do you think this is a problem with my phone or with the school somehow? All the people I know were on the network last year and have no problems but due to an update that came out I had to forgo all of my saved networks. I appreciate any insight that I can get on this thank you.

Comment: Do you see some hotspots at school and other not or are all invisible to your phone? have you checked the Wifi list provided by a Wifi Scanner such as [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer)

Comment: I did try that but it didn't show anything when I launched it; however, that could have been because I got impatient after about 20 seconds. I'll try it again thanks,

Comment: Realized why it didn't work earlier by testing at home. It needed the location to be on for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your phone's WiFi capabilities might not meet the supported range of your school WiFi networks. For example I have a 2.4ghz wifi network and a 5ghz wifi network from my router. The 5ghz frequency can only be seen on iPhones and not my android device personally, as iPhones tend to support higher wifi frequencies than most androids.

Comment: Ah okay thank you I'll have to check that out later then

Comment: Note that this is probably subjective: for example, my Android device can see both 2.4GHz and 5GHz networks, but notice that the latter frequency tend to be easily stopped by thick materials or reflected by metal.